# How to use np.where while reading multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column called **condition** where it reads three different columns and fill it's rows based on given conditions. the dataset looks like this:

```
print(df)

      IgG    NC1    PCR
0     Neg    Pos    not_detec
1     Neg    Neg    not_detec
2     Pos    Neg    detec
```

What I'm trying to do is that if **IgG** is negative, **NC1** is negative and **PCR** is not_detec it will give me negative else, positive.

So, my desired outcome is this

```
print(df)

      IgG    NC1    PCR         condition
0     Neg    Pos    not_detec   Pos
1     Neg    Neg    not_detec   Neg
2     Pos    Neg    detec       Pos
```

I tried doing by typing the following,

```
df['condition'] = np.where((df['IgM']=='Neg') & (df['NS1']=='Neg') & df['PCR']== 'not_detec'), 'Negative', 'Positive')
```

But, I got a syntax error.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: missing `(` from `hesn['PCR']== 'not_detec')`

Comment: WOW I didn't notice that. Thank you! @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

As @jezrael commented, it was missing `(` from `df[PCR]=='not_detec'`